# MVC Jquery/Controller Post Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm struggling to achieve the following, I have a page where a user Logs a Call, the user needs to input various fields and selects from several dropdowns, I then need to post that data (either via JQuery or the controller) to another page, where the user can view the entered data and decide to commit it or not.

I've been going back and fourth for ages now, trying to figure out how to post data from my cshtml to my controller and then redirect to another page with that data persisting.

I've tried to redirect via JQuery and/or the controller and just can't seem to get one or the other working.

Code extracts below:

cshtml:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: dir + '/Submit/',
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(callData),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            complete: function () { },
            success: function (data) {
            }
        })
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(SupportCallModel callData)
    {
        SupportCallModel newData = new SupportCallModel();

        newData.SupportCallID = 1;
        newData.CallTypeID = callData.CallTypeID;
        newData.TroubleShooting = callData.TroubleShooting;
        newData.EmailRequest = callData.EmailRequest;
        newData.MailDate = callData.MailDate;
        newData.FSEOnSite = callData.FSEOnSite;
        newData.FSEEmployeeID = callData.FSEEmployeeID;
        newData.CallCategory = callData.CallCategory;
        newData.CallType = callData.CallType;
        newData.CallItem = callData.CallItem;
        newData.Summary = callData.Summary;
        newData.Description = callData.Description;
        newData.ExternalReference = callData.ExternalReference;
        newData.CallStatusID = callData.CallStatusID;
        newData.CallPriorityID = callData.CallPriorityID;
        newData.CallCoEmployeeID = callData.CallCoEmployeeID;

        return RedirectToAction("Verify", newData);
    }

    public ActionResult Verify(SupportCallModel postData)
    {
        return View(postData);
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked in your dev tools or with Fiddler to see the POST and if there's an error?

Comment: why you stringify `JSON.stringify(callData)`? I think MVC model binding works fine here.

Comment: Currently not receiving any errors.
The controller is just not redirecting to the "Verify" page.
If I add something like "window.location.href = "/SupportCall/Verify/callData?"+JSON.stringify(callData)" to the success of the AJAX post, it redirects but without the data

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh, if I remove the JSON.stringify(callData), I get "POST http://localhost:57980/SupportCall/Submit/ 500 (Internal Server Error) "

Comment: good. tell us about the error. read response.

Comment: The error on removing "JSON.stringify(callData)" creates the following error:
POST http://localhost:57980/SupportCall/Submit/ 500 (Internal Server Error) 
-send
-jQuery.extend.ajax
-(anonymous function)
-jQuery.event.dispatch
-elemData.handle
..
I don't think the problem is there though, as when I leave the code in place, the data gets sent to the controller and I can view it fine, it's just not redirecting to the "Verify" page even though I step through the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax is pointless since ajax calls stay on the same page (`return RedirectToAction("Verify", newData);` is ignored). You can just do a normal submit. Assuming your rendering all the required inputs for `SupportCallModel` in view, then it will post back. I would recommend you include

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(SupportCallModel callData)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(callData);
  }
  ...
```

at the top of the method in case the model contains validation errors.

You then create a new instance of `SupportCallModel` based on the properties of `callData` which also seems pointless (why not just pass `callData` instead of `newData`?)

If `SupportCallModel` contains only properties which are Value types then you can use `return RedirectToAction("Verify", newData);` or `return RedirectToAction("Verify", callData);`. Internally a `RouteValueDictionary` is created based on the name and value of each property and `postData` will be correctly bound in the `Verify()` method. If however any of the properties are complex types or collections then binding will fail for those properties. In that case you need to persist the model so it can be retrieved in the `Verify` method. My recommendation would be to persist to the database (either a separate table or the existing table that includes a field indicating a pending status), but you could use `Session` or `TempData` (in conjuction with `.Peek` so its not lost if the user hits the refresh button).

I'm not sure exactly what the `Verify` GET method is rendering, but if it does not include controls for all properties then the `Verify` submit button will need to post back some ID value that allows you the retrieve the model again from the database or session and finally save it to the database.

Comment: What I ended up doing to get it working, is adding the List into a Session in the ActionResult Submit(), navigating to the Verify page on the Success from AJAX and then retrieving the list back from the session

Answer (score 0):

In your url post...

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Submit","{ControllerName}")',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(callData),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function () { },
        success: function (data) {
              window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Verify","{ControllerName}", Model);'
        }
    })
```

Comment: Same problem persists.
When it hits the "return RedirectToAction("Verify", newData);"
The "Verify" ActionResult is called but the page does not redirect

Comment: I don't even really understand why you're using jquery for this at all, it's adding a layer of indirection to everything you're doing and making extremely simple code fail to run properly.

Comment: Some of the logic used to derive data from the drop downs is done via JQuery. It's then passed to the 'callData' object,  which some validation is done against.
Not sure of another way to then pass the data back to the controller.

Comment: I mean, there's already ways of doing data validation using jqueryval and attribute decorations on your models. This all seems very strange.

Comment: Doesn't that still leave me with the same problem? How can I pass var callData = {
            CallTypeID: $('#callType').val(), TroubleShooting: $('#chkTroubleShoot').is(":checked"),... } back to the controller without JQuery?

Comment: Teaching you how MVC works is a bit outside the scope of this question... but you shouldn't have to be manually declaring #chkTroubleshoot, it should be a bool property on your viewmodel and rendered with a @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Troubleshoot);

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're redirecting on the server side when you're making the call via AJAX.
Your redirects should be made on the client side since you're calling the `ActionResult` on a non-traditional sense (AJAX).

You can remove the `return RedirectToAction("Verify", newData);` from your action result since it will not do anything. You can probably just return something that specifies whether the call was valid or not.

For your data to persist on another page, you will have to save the data into a temp table in DB so you can show it when you do a redirect.

```
  $.ajax({
     url: dir + '/Submit/',
     async: true,
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(callData),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     complete: function () { 
     },
     success: function (data) {
         if (data && data.isValid) {
             // Grab the tempId that was saved temporarily for verification.
             var tempId = data.tempId;

             // Perform redirect
             window.location = dir + '/Verify/' + tempId;
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: How can I persist the data on the new page?
Since I'm not committing the data yet, the verify page will have the function to save the data to the db.

Comment: You will have to save it in the DB if you want to view the data on another page. Is there a reason for doing that? Can't you verify within the same page?

Comment: It's part of the design that's currently been chosen, the user enters all the data, then views it on the other screen before committing it, a Reference Number will then need to be generated and displayed to the user and then return to a dashboard.

Is it possible to add the data to a Session variable which can be passed to the other screen?

Comment: You can use a session variable but there some limitations, but certainly you can.

Answer (score 0):

You could model this all without Ajax using standard form posts to MVC controllers reasonably simply.

Assuming your flow looks something like this:

[image: Submit -> Verify process flow]

Make the Submit POST return a view containing the data sent in the model.  If that data can be verified make the view allow the data on that form to be posted to a Confirm controller action.

In this design the data is entirely transient, the data sent in the HTTP form payload on the initial post is then returned as a form within the returned HTML.  This data is then in turn sent to the Verify action.

To do this in your case I think it might be as simple as calling the Submit with the Post verb as a none Ajax call and amending it so the return line looks like `return View("Verify", newData);`

You will also obviously need to do something else with Verify to do something in that action method.